# Why I can put header to the center. But can't put header child to the center?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <title>Test Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>MarioClub</h1>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

With this css module:

```
header {
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    background: yellow;
    border-width: medium;
    border-color: black;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

header h1 {
    /*text-align: center;*/
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border: 8px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

When I put "text-align: center;" into the "header" selector, It work as well. But when I remove it from header, and add to "header h1" selector, text-align does not work. Why it's not work?

I think it have to work conversely, because I want to put "h1"s text to the center, but not all "headers" text.

[image: It work like this when I put text-aling to the "header" selector]
It work like this when I put text-aling to the "header" selector

[image: And like this when I put it into "header h1" selector]
And like this when I put it into "header h1" selector

Comment: It's because your H1 is `inline-block`...which cannot be centered using text align on it. That has to be on the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `text-align` on the `h1` only aligns the text inside it, not itself. Putting `text-align` on the `header` aligns all of the `header`'s children.

Answer (score 0):

Because inline-block doesn't get full parent width, so, althought its text is centered, it doesn't seem that. Just inspect h1 element with your browser inspector, and see the difference in both cases.